# Chrome web audio not played when audio src changed using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code which plays audio sounds on mouse move. Right now it is has only one sound for left and another sound for right. but when i use a random method to use different sounds from an array every time the mouse move, the audio doesn't play.
Basically i am setting attribute to audio src the new sound file index, But chrome not playing audio.

this is the demo link:
http://angeloplessas.com/flame/6/index5.html

and this is the link which is working with each sounds on left and right
http://angeloplessas.com/flame/6/index2.html

```
function getRandomSound() {
  var sounds = ["sound/New/new3.mp3", "sound/New/new4.mp3", "sound/New/new5.mp3", "sound/New/new6.mp3", "sound/New/new7.mp3", "sound/New/new8.mp3", "sound/New/new9.mp3", "sound/New/new10.mp3", "sound/left.mp3", "sound/right.mp3"];
  var indexLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sounds.length));
  var indexRight = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sounds.length));
  var audioElementLeft = document.getElementById('left-audio');
  audioElementLeft.setAttribute('src', sounds[indexLeft]);
  var audioElementRight = document.getElementById('right-audio');
  audioElementRight.setAttribute('src', sounds[indexRight]);
}
```

I am using `getRandomSound()` in mouse move function.

I am getting an error as `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException`

The expected result should be audio should play on left and right speakers.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can get `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException` error in different cases, most commonly:

- Your audio file is played before it loads (sound data loads asynchronously). In this case, you can pre-load audio files, and use the `audio.oncanplaythrough` event to play that sound after it's fully loaded (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplaythrough_event)
- Your audio file is played without an user interaction (you cannot play any sound manually at the start of page loading). See `autoplay` attribute (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#Attributes) to auto-start playing sounds